# Sitecore 8 SPEAK: Getting an Error When calling a Method in JS File

Tags: jquery, sitecore

When I calling a method in JS file from Sitecore SPEAK application once a button clicked, I'm getting the following error message:

**TypeError: this.product is not a function
this.product()**

`this.product()` is the function name:

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
var model = Sitecore.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super();
    },
    products: function () {
        var input = this.get("input");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/sitecore/Product/Find",
            type: "POST",
            data: { input: input },
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {
                this.set("output", data);
            }
        });
    },

    product: function () {
        var input2 = this.get("input2");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/sitecore/Product/FindSingle",
            type: "POST",
            data: { input2: input2 },
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {
                this.set("output2", data); 
                this.set("output3", data.TitleS);
            }
        });

        return null;
    },
});

var view = Sitecore.Definitions.Views.ControlView.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super();
    },
    product: function () {
        this.product();
    }
```

});

```
Sitecore.Factories.createComponent("ProductSearch", model, view, ".sc-ProductSearch");
```

});

Calling the above method from SPEAK Button.Click event as:
**javascript:app.product();**

What can we do to avoid such case?

Comment: Have you added PageCode component to the page ?

Comment: Yes, PageCode is added on the top of the layout

Comment: Can you post your entire js code ? It seems that everything should be working fine if the extensions method is extending. Is your code placed into an extension block like this define(["sitecore"], function(Sitecore) {
    var app = Sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({ ?

Comment: I have an example SPEAK PageCode here. The DeleteArticle and AddArticle are wired up to SPEAK buttons. Does your PageCode differ from this? https://github.com/sobek1985/EntityServiceDemo/blob/master/EntityServiceDemo/EntityServiceDemo.js

Comment: I have updated the js code with the entire code @sobek1985 yes it is differ than mine so I'll check this. Which version of sitecore you are using?

Comment: That example is Sitecore 8. However the general structure of SPEAK doesn't change between 7.2-8. Only new components added etc. This is SPEAK 1.1 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your PageCode for your SPEAK application can you update the JavaScript to extend Sitecore.Definitions.App rather than Sitecore.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend?

Eg. define the SPEAK application like this.

```
define(["sitecore", "jquery", "underscore"], function (Sitecore, $, _) {
var SpeakExample = Sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({initialize: function (options) {
},

products: function () {
    var input = this.get("input");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/sitecore/Product/Find",
        type: "POST",
        data: { input: input },
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            this.set("output", data);
        }
    });
},

product: function () {
    var input2 = this.get("input2");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/sitecore/Product/FindSingle",
        type: "POST",
        data: { input2: input2 },
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            this.set("output2", data); 
            this.set("output3", data.TitleS);
        }
    });

    return null;
},return SpeakExample;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
   define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
        var model = Sitecore.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend({
            initialize: function (options) {
                this._super();
                app = this;
            },
        products: function () {}
        });
    }
```

And in the button click type: javascript:app.ProductSearch.product()

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `this.model.product()` instead of `this.product()` in the product method inside your view definition.